# incorrect result showing in K nearest neighbour approach

Tags: python-3.x, function, coordinates, knn, closest-points

I am reforming the 2D coordinate number in a aligned way which was not aligned (coordinate numbers were suffled) before.

I have below input coordinates,

```
X = [2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5] 
Y = [2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I have to make it aligned. Therefore, I first applied `Sorted` function on this coordinates. I got below output after it.

```
merged_list1 = sorted(zip(X, Y))
```

output

```
X1_coordinate_reformed = [2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
Y1_coordinate_reformed = [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Still it iot aligned properly. I want two consecutive nodes place next to each other. Therefore I am applying the approach to find the nearest coordinate from origin to find the very first node. Then from the first node, I found another nearest coordinate and so on...For that, I have applied below code,

First I wrote a function which calculates the distance and gives index of the nearest coordinate from the list.

```
def solve(pts, pt):
    x, y = pt
    idx = -1
    smallest = float("inf")
    for p in pts:
        if p[0] == x or p[1] == y:
            dist = abs(x - p[0]) + abs(y - p[1])
            if dist < smallest:
                idx = pts.index(p)
                smallest = dist
            elif dist == smallest:
                if pts.index(p) < idx:
                    idx = pts.index(p)
                    smallest = dist
    return idx

coor2 = list(zip(X1_coordinate_reformed, Y1_coordinate_reformed))  # make a list which contains tuples of X and Y coordinates
pts2 = coor2.copy()
origin1 = (0, 0)

new_coor1 = []

for i in range(len(pts2)):
    pt = origin1
    
    index_num1 = solve(pts2, pt)
    print('index is', index_num1)
    
    origin1 = pts2[index_num1]
    new_coor1.append(pts2[index_num1])
    del pts2[index_num1]
```

After running the code, I got below output,

```
[(6, 6), (5, 6), (4, 6), (4, 5), (4, 4), (4, 3), (3, 3), (2, 3), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (6, 5), (6, 4), (6, 3), (6, 2)]
```

Which is not correct because it can be clearly understand that,

```
coor2 = [(2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2), (3, 3), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 6), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5), (6, 6)]

origin = (0, 0)
```

if we find the distance between Origin which was (0, 0) in very first and from every coordinate from above `coor2` list, we will get `(2,2)` is nearest coordinate. Then How come my code gives `(6,6)` is the nearest coordinate??

The interesting thing is, if I apply the same procedure (sorting followed by finding nearest coordinate) on below coordinates,

```
X2_coordinate = [2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 1, 3, 4, 3, 1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 2, 0]
Y2_coordinate = [3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

After applying `sorted` function

```
X2_coordinate_reformed = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
Y2_coordinate_reformed = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

After applying method of searching nearest coordinates mentioned above, the result I got

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4), (3, 3), (3, 2), (3, 1), (3, 0), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4)]
```

Kindly suggest me where I am doing wrong and what should I change??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use `scipy` for finding closest coordinate.

The code given below works.

```
from scipy import spatial

pts = merged_list1.copy()

origin = (0, 0)
origin = np.array(origin)

new_coordi = []
for i in range(len(pts)):
    x = origin
    distance,index = spatial.KDTree(pts).query(x)
    new_coordi.append(pts[index])
    origin = np.array(pts[index])
    del pts[index]
```

Comment: On above answer, suggestions for improvement are always welcomed!